# How do you get burned wood off of a glass stovetop?

Tags: cleaning, glass, mistakes

I accidentally set a cork trivet on fire on top of my glass stovetop the other week, and it's left behind a gray burned on spot that feels different to the touch. I can't figure out how to get it off; I've used stovetop cleaner, baking soda, the little scraper thing, vinegar, and glass cleaner spray. Its still there. How do I get it off?

Comment: @dandavis if you have some suggestion how to solve the problem, please post it as an answer. Even if you are not certain it will work, and even if you cannot go in depth with a long explanation. If it is such a long shot that you doubt it is worth posting as an answer, please don't post it at all.

Comment: I'm surprised the glass top cleaner didn't work. What scrubbing utensil are you using with it? Did you shake the cleaner well before using? Does your method of using it reliably remove other burned on stuff?  What does the spot feel like, e.g. rough or sticky?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Does the gray area feel raised up from the glass, as if something is still stuck there, or rough but flat, like the glass itself has been damaged/discoloured?

Comment: @FuzzyChef the area is rough and raised up, it's definitely stuck there and not discoloration. We were able to get a tiny bit off with a scraper tool but only a small amount.

Comment: @Kat we were originally just using paper towels but we also tried steel wool, and yes we shook the cleaner before using. Normally this is enough to get rid of anything else that's burned on . The spot is rough to the touch.

Comment: Here's what I'd try.  Not posting this as an answer because I don't know if any of it will actually work:  barkeepers friend & a scrubby, Dawn power dissolver, and then a razor-blade scraper for paint removal.

Answer (score 4):

Some people might be inclined to think your glass is damaged rather than dirty, and that's why you can't get it clean. In a comment you say that the discoloration is raised, which suggests that's not the case.  However cook tops are, by definition, heat resistant, and I'm also assuming you didn't let this fire rage out of control for an extended period of time. I believe you're correct and the glass is fine, just dirty.

You've mostly done what I would try except I would use a scrubber sponge designed for glass cook tops. Get a fresh one, spritz it with a bit of water (it seems to scrub less well if it's too wet or completely dry), apply a generous amount of cleaner and start scrubbing with as much force as you can muster. If your sponge turns black or grey then you know it *is* working, even if it's slow. Move to a new spot on the sponge if it gets dirty enough that it's not rough to the touch anymore. You may have to scrub a lot. You could also try a different brand of cleaner, some do work better than others.

You could also try a razor blade, unless that's what you mean by "scraper tool". This is a pretty common method of getting burnt-on stuff off of glass cook tops, though I've never personally had to resort to it. If there's a lot of gunk, it may save you some scrubbing.

I tried looking for solvents that are safe to use, but wasn't able to find any. I even found a note that you shouldn't use regular glass cleaner because the ammonia in it isn't good for glass cook tops. I'm not sure if that's true, but you might want to avoid trying that again. It's only good for smudges anyway, so there's no reason to risk it.

My only other thought is to try soaking a towel in hot water and putting that on the gunk for a bit before scrubbing, as maybe that will soften it up. Wipe up excess water before scrubbing so the abrasives in the cleaner can do their work instead of just swimming in water.

Good luck! If you do solve it, please report back what worked best.

Comment: Similar to your advice on soaking a towel: If you're in a particularly dry area, I've seen recommendations to soak a paper towel with whatever solvent / cleaner, then a layer of plastic wrap.  (but those were for dealing with other types of issues, not necessarily burned wood on glass)

Answer (score 1):

I have had great results using a single-edge razor blade to clean discolorations from my glass cook top.  I am religious about keeping my surfaces clean, but sometimes heat and "some unseen agent" form a discoloration that routine cleaning won't remove.  Razor blade to the rescue!